# Anyway to overwrite parts of a json file in java?

Tags: java, json

I need to be able to parse sql calls from a database to json and then compare the key fields in the parsed JSON string against a json file (it's technically a BOD --Business Object Document) and if they match then I need to overwrite the json file's matching value with that of the JSON string.

e.g. I parse the sql call to this

```
{
"partyInfo": {
    "PARTY_NAME": "NORWAY",
    "STATE": "OSLO",
    "PARTY_ID": "92706031",
    "VERTICAL_MARKET_TOP_DESC": null,
    "ATTRIBUTE20": null,
    "DUNS_NUMBER": null,
    "SIC_CODE": null,
    "EMPLOYEES_TOTAL": null,
    "ALL_ADDRESS_LINES": "HOMMENKOLLEN 23 TOPPEN 12",
    "CITY": "OSLO",
    "POSTAL_CODE": "1255",
    "COUNTRY_NAME": "NORWAY",
    "KNOWN_AS": null
}
```

}

and then compare it against a file that looks like this:

```
{
"partyInfo": {
    "PARTY_NAME": string,
    "STATE": string,
    "PARTY_ID": number,
    "SIC_CODE": string,
}
```

}

and overwriting values on matching keys s.t that the ending file looks like this:

```
   {
"partyInfo": {
    "PARTY_NAME": "NORWAY",
    "STATE": "OSLO",
    "PARTY_ID": "92706031",
    "SIC_CODE": null,
}
```

}

So far I've been able to parse the SQL calls to JSON (using Jackson right now but I'm willing to change if need be) but I don't know how to compare against the file and overwrite only the data values that match up.

Comment: I would think you would want to decode the BOD document to an object, iterate through the properties of the object, comparing them against the DB results with same key and overwriting the value in the BOD, then encode the BOD back to JSON for persisting it.  I don't see any reason to actually encode the DB results to JSON unless you need to persist this data in JSON for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the tree model allows you to update nodes.

Here's an example:
http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes#Tree_Model_Example

Comment: This was actually extremely useful

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding what you're wanting to do, but it sounds like you could just use a `for` loop over the keys in the `Map` representing the JSON from the file, compare the values to those in the database, change any that don't match, and then write the file back out:

```
for(String key: fileJson.keys())
    if(!fileJson.get(key).equals(sqlJson.get(key)))
        fileJson.put(key, sqlJson.get(key));

// write fileJson back out to the correct file through Jackson
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to parse these files into java objects (using Jackson again), compare the objects and then save what you need to save.

Otherwise you'll effectively be making something like the [patch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_%28Unix%29) tool.